# stuck in starting about pyspark --master yarn

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have a problem about starting SPARK ON YARN. The steps are as follow:

1. Make sure Spark Standalone is not running: `$./stop-all.sh`
2. Make sure the HADOOP_CONF_DIR environment variable was set in ~/.bashrc at the client node.

   ```
   export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
   ```
3. Configure yarn-site.xml to supprt running Spark programs

   ```xml
   <configuration>
     <property>
       <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
       <value>false</value>
     </property>
   </configuration>
   ```
4. Configure yarn-env.sh

   ```sh
   export JAVA_HOME=/home/spark/jdk1.8.0_251
   export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

   export HADOOP_HOME=/home/spark/hadoop-2.10.1
   export PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$PATH

   export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop

   export ANACONDA_HOME=/home/spark/anaconda3
   export PATH=$ANACONDA_HOME/bin:$PATH
   ```
5. Put Spark-related program that are needed to be used on YARN on HDFS

   ```
   hadoop fs -mkdir /user/spark/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7
   hadoop fs -put ~/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/jars spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7
   ```
6. Configure spark-defaults.conf and specify the Spark-related program that are needed to be used on YARN

   ```
   spark.yarn.jars hdfs://devenv/user/${USER}/spark-2.4.5/jars/*
   ```
7. Start YARN and check the web console

   ```
   ./start-yarn.sh
   ```

   And I can see the yarn webui on `http://username:8088`
8. Test it and run some Spark programs

   ```
   pyspark --master yarn
   ```

But when I try to start spark on yarn
it stuck at a weird situation like this:

[image]

this is my setting in user .bashrc:

[image]

Comment: I think you should remove `JAVA_HOME=/usr`. Not saying that will fix it, but it definitely isn't correct

Comment: So, if you launch the pyspark shell, does it appear on the YARN UI? It should, but it might say that resources are waiting to be allocated

Comment: Yes, you're right. it indeed shows pyspark_shell, but no memory and core. I'm so confuse about it.